# Owin Middleware – OnSendingHeaders callback is called twice

Tags: c#, owin

In my Owin Middleware I subscribe a callback to the OnSendingHeaders. In my UnitTests, the callback is *sometimes* called twice. Most of the time, the first TestCase succeeds and the second fails. Sometimes both succeed, sometimes both fail. I also encountered this problem in production.

As I understand the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.owinresponse.onsendingheaders(v=vs.113).aspx), this Callback should only be called once. Do I misunderstand the documentation? Or is this a bug? And is there a “clean” way to deal with this behavior?

```
public class MyMiddleware
{
    public void Initialize(Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task> next) { }

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> env)
    {
        IOwinContext context = new OwinContext(env);
        context.Response.OnSendingHeaders(dummy =>
        {
            Count++;
        }, null);

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("something");
    }
}


[TestFixture]
public class MyMiddlewareTests
{
    [TestCase(1), TestCase(2)]
    public async Task TheTest(int dummy)
    {
        var myMiddleware = new MyMiddleware();
        using (var server = TestServer.Create(app => { app.Use(myMiddleware); }))
        {
            var response = await server.HttpClient.GetAsync("/");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, myMiddleware.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: In the original question I stated that I haven't seen the problem occuring in production. This changed, so the problem isn't test-only.

Edit 2: We realized that we have a different problem on production, i.e. I can only confirm that the callback is called twice with the testserver.